# Project updates don't show up on mobile device

Tags: android, libgdx

I've made a small application with libgdx framework, which works perfectly on desktop. It runs on Android too, however once I change something in my main project and try to recompile it on my phone, it seems like the Android still runs the old version.

I've tried to re-install the app, but it does not help. The only way I can see the changes on my phone is to recreate a different Android project.

Any ideas what might be causing this kind of behavior?

My projects are created the way it is shown here: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup

EDIT: Not sure why, but everything seems to work fine after "re-installing" Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the fault of eclipse, not libgdx. Please check whether you tick Project->Build Automaticcally or not. Or else you can try to build by ant in command line. This is my complete compiling script:

```
cd "project_folder"
adb uninstall com.package
call ant clean
call ant debug
adb install "bin\project_debug.apk"
adb shell am start -n com.package/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but it didn't work. It's so frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, though I don't remember exact solution. It was one-time problem, which never appeared before and after and was also unexpected (I didn't do anything different from what I have done all the time). Try these steps:

- remove your app from Android device
- manually remove all directories containing bin data from every project associated with your game; rebuild all projects
- restart your IDE and Android device (I suppose this is most important for Android device)
- uncheck auto-build

You might also want to test it with other device, if available, to narrow possibilities.